# How to assign to a variable, the value typed in an input element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this html element

```
<label for="minV">Minimum value</label>
          <input
            class="inputCell"
            type="number"
            value="6"
            id="minV"
            onclick="this.select()"
          />
```

[This is how I see it in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxhLa.png)

I changed the value from 6 to 10.
I want to assign the new value to a variable in js. If I'm doing this:

```
let min = Number(document.querySelector("#minV").value);
```

the 'min' variable will be always have value 6.

How can I assign to the variable 'min' the value that I have typed in the input element?

Comment: You need create `oninput` event listener on `<input>` element and update your `min` variable inside that listener. https://jsfiddle.net/tfdpa1kL/

Answer (score 1):

If you only call set `min` once that won't do, you need to keep updating `min` every time the input changes.
Create a function that does what you want and call it from the input's `onchange` property (or set up an event listener, whatever you like).

```js
let min = undefined;

function onChange() {
  const input = document.querySelector("#minV");
  min = input.value;
  console.log(min);
}
```

```html
<label for="minV">Minimum value</label>
<input class="inputCell" type="number" value="6" id="minV" onclick="this.select()" onchange="onChange()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/min) attribute. Additionally you can use a handler to assign a value (here to the global variable called `min`) and keep that value above or equal to minimum on the value of the min-attribute. The snippet uses [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to handle stuff.

```js
let min = 6; // <= always 6 or up
// listen to keyup/mouseup/-down events
document.addEventListener(`keyup`, handle);
document.addEventListener(`mousedown`, handle);
document.addEventListener(`mouseup`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  // only act on input#minV
  if (evt.target.id === `minV` &&
      /\d|backspace|delete|up|down/i.test(evt.key) || 
      /^mouse/i.test(evt.type)) {
    const inp = evt.target;
    const inpMin = inp.getAttribute(`min`);
    // min magic here
    min = inp.value < +inpMin ? inpMin : inp.value;
    // display value for demo
    document.querySelector(`.minValue`).textContent = 
      `Minumum value: ${min}`;
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="minV">Minimum value</label>
<input class="inputCell" 
  type="number" value="6" id="minV" min="6" />

<p class="minValue">Minimum value: -</p>
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question...

Answer (score 0):

Something like that will help?

```
<label for="minV">Minimum value</label>
          <input
            class="inputCell"
            type="number"
            value="6"
            id="minV"
            onclick="this.select()"
            onchange="myFunction()"
          />
```

Script

```
var min = 6
function myFunction(){
    min = Number(document.querySelector("#minV").value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use addEventListener to listen the input's value change

For example:

```js
let minVofInput = document.querySelector('#minV');
let min = 6;  //  initial value

minVofInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
  min = minVofInput.value;   // assign input's value to variable min
})
```